# Copy files to directory based on user input and using * to list files

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a extremely simple bash script, `my_copy.sh`, that reads arbitrary number of input files, a destination directory, and finally asks for confirmation if you want to copy the files.

Example usage: `./my_copy.sh`

```
 Type in the file names to copy:
 file1 file2 Anna Kurt Arne
 Type in the directory to copy to:
 dir_3
 Are you sure you want to copy the files:
 Anna
 Kurt
 Arne
 to the directory dir_3 (y/n)?
```

If the destination directory does not exist, it should be created by the script.

---

My next question:

I want the * character to do a simple `ls` command. So if I type `./my_copy *` , in the command line it should list all files in my directory.

Comment: you should make that two separate questions!

Comment: the script you are proposing is extremely un-unixish. why would you want to force the user to enter all file names by hand, unable to use shell globbing, tab completion, etc.?

Comment: your question is a bit fuzzy... please explain the following: 1) what happened to file1 and file2? 2) what is "my directory"?

Answer (score 4):

Unless the * is escaped or quoted when calling your script, the shell will expand it before you script gets it.

> ./my_copy '*'

or

> ./my_copy \*

It looks like you're trying to add a simple confirmation wrapper around 'cp'. Or are you trying to make it interactively prompt the user?

Comment: Some shells do in fact use an environment variable to indicate which parameters are a result of wildcard expansion. However, assuming you know which shell the user has might not be the wisest of ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "cp -i", which makes it interactive and prompt before overwriting. You could also add that as an alias to .bash_profile, so it always prompts.

Answer (score 1):

Your second question is quite difficult. The shell will attempt to interpret * and replace it with all items in the current directory. The only way the shell will give you a * as the only entry in the argument list is if all the files in the directory have names starting with a dot. So, your example command would actually get called with $0 = my_copy and $1 = my_copy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give * as argument, but you can replace it with letter "e" for example and do this:

```
if [ "$1" = "e" ]
then
    ls
else
    return 0
fi
```